# Python 3 - How to write specific row in same file csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to update a fieldname called "done" in same file csv

This is structure of file csv:

Input:

```
Email            Done
 1@gmail.com       
 2@gmail.com       
 3@gmail.com
 4@gmail.com
```

Output:

```
Email            Done
 1@gmail.com       1
 2@gmail.com       1
 3@gmail.com       1
 4@gmail.com       1
```

What I want look like:

```
import csv
with open(r'E:\test.csv','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter='|')

    for row in reader:
      #do something here#
      #then write "1" to filename "done"
f.close()
```

How to do it ? Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: Important points here are; how big is the data file? Will you be okay with this being in memory? Are you alright with a model that reads once, writes once, and handles the edits in memory?

The reason I ask this is; it is going to be far more performant if you load the CSV into memory as a data structure, keep it there, do your edits, and write back to disk in the final format, if your problem supports it. Otherwise the piecemeal read/writes are gong to kill your performance, and, it is easier to deal with an in-memory data structure than text on disk.

Comment: Yes, it is okay with this being in memory. This is not big data

Comment: Then you should read the data from the csv, instantiate that as a tuple in memory, or a map, if you want random read/write to the lines, and update the last value as needed. When you are done, or on a periodic basis if you want to guard against data loss, write the data structure back out to the csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a simple change like this you could use a simple pair of read and write files; read a line, and write it back out immediately with the addition.

```
In [6]: with open('test.csv','r') as input:
   ...:    with open('test1.csv','w') as output:
   ...:        header=input.readline()
   ...:        output.write(header)
   ...:        for line in input:
   ...:            output.write('%s %8d\n'%(line.strip(),1))

In [7]: cat test1.csv
Email            Done
1@gmail.com        1
2@gmail.com        1
3@gmail.com        1
4@gmail.com        1
```

You could also use a csv reader and csv writer; A `numpy` user might be tempted to use the `loadtxt` and `savetxt` pair, though mixing string and number values in an array takes a bit more know-how.

In a new enough Python you could put both opens in one with context:

```
with open('test.csv','r') as input, open('test1.csv','w') as output:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you but how to write to same file ?

Comment: You can't without overwriting the next line.  Better make a new file, and rename them after.